# PHP/MySql Determining age/Elapsed Time of inserted data

Tags: php, mysql

I honestly have no idea on how to explain this, so if you look at http://www.gw2lfg.com, the elapsed time column is what I am trying to do, determine if something is a minute old, two minutes old, etc. thanks for all the help

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just generate a timestamp at insertion, and then compare against this timestamp on generation?

Comment: I can't figure out how to generate a Timestamp at insertion, I have the timestamp field, but I don't know how to actually make it work for the input box, I'm still learning hehe

Comment: Use the php function [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: So then would I turn off fetching the timestamp from the database? blah I'm pretty confused >:C

Answer (score 0):

your looking for time elapse you can do the following.

```
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-12-01 12:12:12') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME());
```

you can then convert it into seconds and minutes.

Comment: I'm still beginning so I have almost no idea on how to do this, is this a field I add or?

Answer (score 0):

Try this working example,

```
function time_ago($date)
    {

        if (empty($date)) { // $date=> mysql timestatmp
            return "No date provided";
        }      
        $periods    = array("sec", "min", "hr", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
        $lengths    = array("60","60","24","7");

        $now        = time();
        $unix_date  = strtotime($date);
        // check validity of date
        if (empty($unix_date)) {   
            return "Bad date";
        }
        // is it future date or past date
        if ($now >= $unix_date) {   
            $difference = $now - $unix_date;
            $tense      = "ago";
        } else {
            $difference = $unix_date - $now;
            $tense      = "from now";
        }
        for ($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
            $difference /= $lengths[$j];
        }
            $difference  = round($difference);

        if ($difference != 1 && $j != 0) {
            $periods[$j].= "s";
        }
        if($difference!=0)
        return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
        else
        return "a few seconds ago";
    }
```

**Update:**

Usage:

```
echo time_ago('2013-07-01 11:30:00'); // Output: 5 mins ago
```

Comment: I'm honestly not sure where to put it, do I call the function in my input box and disable it? I have a thing where it fetches all fields from the database and displays it in a table. When you insert something into the table the input box for time is where I'm confused

Comment: Hmm alright, I see it says 10hrs from now when I put that usage in, so I'm assuming I have to declare a date variable to be what? current_time or something? Thanks for all the help

Comment: Ahh this is so frustrating, I can't figure out how to get the $date to work

Comment: 10hrs from now means you would have gave the future time or check the php timezone, set the default timezone in php.

Comment: I want it so when a user submits into the table, it is automatically timestamped and it starts counting from their, so in 1 minute the text will say 1 minute ago, etc. How do I do this though, I've been sitting here for 6 hours now googling ;c